# INSERT query with PHP variable values

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to insert value to table with PHP mysql command. Insert values pass as php variables. I tried

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO info (nom, prenom, entreprise, email, objet, message) VALUES ('$nom','$prenom','$entreprise','$email','$objet','$message')";
```

this way. But it not works. And also i tried with concatenation it also not working.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked for query errors?

Comment: Learn to use parameterized queries, so your code is not subject to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Is it the only php statement?

Comment: What means `But it not works`? show more code. learn about prepared statements.

Comment: Have you send the query?

Comment: if you show us what errors do you get, we can be able to help you out

Comment: What are the datatypes of your fields in table info?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO info (nom, prenom, entreprise, email, objet, message) VALUES (
'".$nom."',
'".$prenom."',
'".$entreprise."',
'".$email."',
'".$objet."',
'".$message."'
)";
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried what you said. Sorry but its not working.Please tell me any other way. This is sample code i tried                       $f_name = $person->fname;
    $l_name = $person->lname;
    $num = $person->num;
    $login = $person->loginname;
    $pwd = $person->pwd;
    
    $sql1 ="INSERT INTO userDetails( id, firstname, lastname, mobile, userid, password ) VALUES ('".$id."','".$f_name."','".$l_name."','".$num."','".$login."','".$pwd."')";
    $data = mysql_query($sql1, $dbhandle);

Comment: can u share the error that you are getting?. Also table structure if you can. That will help me to find the error.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I only did mistake. I inserted the duplicate value for primary key. Now it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `info` (`nom`, `prenom`, `entreprise`,`email`,`objet`,`message`) VALUES ('$nom','$prenom','$entreprise','$email','$objet','$message')";
```

Comment: There aren't reserved keyword used in the fields name. No need to use the backtick.